# Let R = Z[X]. Show that: I = {n + XP : $n\in2Z$, $P\in R$} is an ideal of R and that it is not a principal ideal

Tags: ring-theory

Let R = Z[X]. 
Show that: **I = {n + XP : $n\in2Z$, $P\in R$}** is an ideal of R and that it is
not a principal ideal.

i know what the ideal and principal ideal means but get stuck when proving it 
please help

thanks

Comment: Can you describe your ideal in terms of generators?

Comment: no i can't how do you describe them as generators

Comment: Well you're looking at any polynomial so long as its constant term is even. How can you represent these with some (finite) number of generators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that $\langle p\rangle\ne I$ for all $p\in I$. Pick $p\in I$, and proceed by cases:

(a)  if $p=0$ then $\langle p\rangle=0$ which is different from $I$.

(b) if $p$ is a polynomial of degree greater than $1$, then $\langle p\rangle\ne I$ as $2\in I\setminus \langle p\rangle$.

(c) if $p\in\mathbb Z$, then $p$ is even so every $q\in \langle p\rangle$ is a polynomial with all coefficients even, hence $x+2\in I\setminus \langle p\rangle$.

So $I$ cannot be generated by any of its elements.

Comment: does both case (a) and case (b) still stand when n=0 and why do we need case (c) is case (b) not suffiecient and thanks for your answer